# How to uninstall fink from iMac running OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mountain-lion, fink

I made a mistake installing fink on my iMac running OS X 10.8.   I typed in a command to uninstall from the fink website http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-fink.php?phpLang=en#removing

```
fink remove --recursive daemonic xinitrc
```

…but I got the error message:

```
Failed: no package specified for command 'remove --recursive'!
```

I have not installed anything with fink, so can I safely skip this command and use the following command instead?

```
sudo rm -rf /sw
```

Comment: The rm command seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be deleted, if it's not going to be answered.